# How do I merge different columns in jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains 6 columns

```
        Jaar   Maand   Dag   Uur   Minuut      R10
0       2003       1     1     0        0  0.00000
1       2003       1     1     0       15  0.00000
2       2003       1     1     0       30  0.00000
3       2003       1     1     0       45  0.00000
```

but I would like to have a different format for my data, like in

```
        Year-Month-Day  Hour:Minute      R10
0           2003-01-01        00:00  0.00000
...                ...          ...      ...
```

How can I make from the different columns 3 columns? One for the Year-Month-day, one for the time and one for R10? With python.

Comment: what is your expected output? you tagged matplotlib which is a visualization library?

Comment: Google Translate suggests that `"Jaar Maand Dag Uur Minuut"` is Dutch for `"Year Month Day Hour Minute"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the `datatype` of columns is `integer`. If not `datatype` is `string` remove `.astype(str)` in the code.

```
df_test['Jaar-Maand-Dag'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test.Jaar.astype(str)+'/'+df_test.Maand.astype(str)+'/'+df_test.Dag.astype(str))

df_test['Uur:Minuut'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test.Uur.astype(str)+':'+df_test.Minuut.astype(str),format='%H:%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')

df_test[['Jaar-Maand-Dag','Uur:Minuut','R10']]

    Jaar-Maand-Dag  Uur:Minuut  R10
0       2003-01-01       00:00  0.0
1       2003-01-01       00:15  0.0
2       2003-01-01       00:30  0.0
3       2003-01-01       00:45  0.0
```